# Asp.net - Can't Change Visibility of Panel After Downloading File

Tags: c#, asp.net, download, panel, response

I am displaying a panel that containg a button. When the user clicks the button, it does some processing and then downloads a file for the user.  The code for that is shown here:

```
    private void OpenForm(string content, string formName)
    {
        Byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(content);

        this.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Type", "application/msword");
        this.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Length", bytes.Length.ToString());
        this.Response.AppendHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + formName);
        this.Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);

        ReturnToMemberScreen();

        this.Response.Flush();
        this.Context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
    }
```

In the function ReturnToMemberScreen, I am changing the visibility of some panels.  Here is the function:

```
    private void ReturnToMemberScreen()
    {
        this.panelMappings.Visible = false;
        this.MemberEditPNL.Visible = true;
    }
```

I can download the file perfectly fine, my issue is that the visibility of my panels don't change. Does it have something to do with writing to the Response like I am?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking closer, I think I cannot make any changes to the page because I am changing the Content-Type of the response from "text/html" to application/msword when I do this:

```
this.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Type", "application/msword");
```

As I result, I am making all my changes with CSS and Javascript instead.  By default, I set my panels to either show or hide using css:

```
.hide     
{         
    display:none;     
}

.show
{
    display:block;
}
```

Then I set the `OnClientClick` of the button to the following Javascript function to change the display:

```
function visible() 
{
    document.getElementById('<%=panelForms.ClientID %>').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('<%=MemberEditPNL.ClientID %>').style.display = 'block';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not use Visible = false as that causes the element to not be rendered. Try:

```
// To hide:
 Panel1.Style.Add("display", "none");
// To show:
 Panel1.Style.Add("display", "block");
```

Comment: Have you tried setting make inner panel visible first, then outer panel?

Comment: Tried this and the issue still exists

Answer (score 0):

Do you set the visibility of the panels in the Page_Load event?  If so, and if you're not handling postbacks within the event, then the visibility settings might be overriding the settings in ReturnToMemberScreen.

Comment: Nope, I am not setting them in the Page_Load. I have debugged through the code and I am not doing anything with the visibility of the panels besides the ReturnToMemberScreen function.